# When updating log4j to 2.x, how to deal with changed Level integers?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am updating log4j -> log4j2.

In the old version, the integer value of Level.DEBUG is 10000. ([log4j doc for Level.DEBUG](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html#DEBUG)).
In the new version, the integer value of Level.DEBUG is 500. ([log4j2 doc for Level.DEBUG](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html#DEBUG))

I have code that calls `Level.DEBUG.toInt()` (log4j), which I therefore cannot simply update to `Level.DEBUG.intLevel()` (log4j2)?

Is there some way to use the old numbers in my existing code, 10000 in this case?
In the code I am updating, `Level.DEBUG.toInt()` is input to a public method which takes int-level as input, and I'm not sure which other repos depend on this method's functionality.
Should I alter this method to use the new int-level values, and try to hunt down everywhere it might be called?
Or maybe map it's input to the old version's int-level values (extremely hacky)?
Or is there somewhere in the new version that can map to the old int-level values?